# Create dynamic Laravel accessor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `Product` model and also an `Attribute` model. The relationship between `Product` and `Attribute` is many to many. On my `Product` model I am trying to create a dynamic accessor. I am familiar with Laravel's accessors and mutators feature as documented [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators). The problem I am having is that I do not want to create an accessor every time I create a product attribute.

For example, A product may have a color attribute which could be setup like so:

```
/**
 * Get the product's color.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return string
 */
public function getColorAttribute($value)
{
    foreach ($this->productAttributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->code === 'color') {
            return $attribute->pivot->value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

The product's color could then be accessed like so `$product->color`.
If I where to add a `size` attribute to the product I would need to setup another accessor on the `Product` model so I could access that like so `$product->size`.

**Is there a way I can setup a single "dynamic" accessor to handle all of my attributes when accessed as a property?**

**Do I need to override Laravel's accessor functionality with my own?**

Comment: Perhaps the section *Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models* in [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) is what you need to do instead of going the roundabout way

Comment: I know this is an older question but, just curious but are you using `public $with = ['attributes']` to eager load the attributes onto the `Product` model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can add your own piece of logic into the getAttribute() function of the Eloquent Model class (override it in your model), but in my opinion, it's not a good practice.

Maybe you can have a function:

```
public function getProductAttr($name)
{
    foreach ($this->productAttributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->code === $name) {
            return $attribute->pivot->value;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
$model->getProductAttr('color');
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what  I was thinking too. Except we wouldn't be able to use `getAttribute()` as that would override the method in the `HasAttributes` trait. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You are right, the name is reserved. Fixed the answer.

Comment: You might be interested in https://github.com/topclaudy/eloquent-mutators

Answer (score 5):

Override Magic method -  **__get()** method.

Try this.

```
public function __get($key)
{
    foreach ($this->productAttributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->code === $key) {
            return $attribute->pivot->value;
        }
    }

    return parent::__get($key);
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I don't think Laravel has loaded all of the model's relationships when the `__get` method fires. I'll keep trying though.

Comment: It seems to work with a basic one-to-many relationship. However, I'm using the `withPivot` method when defining my relationship between Product and Attribute. It throws an error at that point. Let me look a bit further into it and see if I can resolve it. Thanks.

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to help. Obviously you can customize this method for any relationships.

Comment: I like this idea in theory, but won't this affect performance on all accessors then?

Answer (score 0):

I think probably Олег Шовкун answer is the right one but if you did want to use the model attribute notation you could get the required argument into the model via a class variable.

```
class YourModel extends Model{

  public $code;

  public function getProductAttribute()
  {
    //a more eloquent way to get the required attribute
    if($attribute = $this->productAttributes->filter(function($attribute){
       return $attribute->code = $this->code;
    })->first()){
        return $attribute->pivot->value;
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Then do

```
$model->code = 'color';
echo $model->product;
```

But its a bit long and pointless